# Is it possible to add a temlate to django CKEditor without editing it's templates-plugin files in site-packages?

Tags: django, ckeditor

There is a file in `lib/python3.6/site-packages/ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/templates/templates/default.js` that i can edit to add more templates to my RichTextFields. But i would really like to track those changes with git and i don't want to add my environment to git.
Is there a way to customize, add templates to **django ckeditor's** templates plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you much about Dijango CKEditor however there is a possibility to add more than one template file to CKEditor using https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-templates and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-templates_files configuration settings. Please see below:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    language: 'en'              
    templates_files : [
        '/ckeditor/plugins/templates/templates/default.js',
        '/ckeditor/my_templates.js'
    ],
    templates : 'default,my_templates'
});
```

Please also have a look at: [CKEditor - how to get the template attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331630/ckeditor-how-to-get-the-template-attributes/50413384#50413384)